# Using the logical "or" in conditional indexing in python arrays

Tags: python, list, indexing, conditional-statements

I want to change the values of some elements in array.
For example, I want all elements that have the values `1`,`2` or `3` to all be mapped to the value `1`.

How can the "or" operator be used for this?  Or any operator that would do what I want. I've tried the code below, and a few other different things, but none of them give what I want:

```
samples = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print samples
samples[samples == 1 or samples == 2 or samples == 3] = 1
print samples
```

I need the output to be:

```
[1,1,1,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate a new list:

```
samples = [1 if i in (1, 2, 3) else i for i in samples]
```

This uses a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to pick between either a `1` or the original value.

Answer (score 1):

An example using `or`; this is no better than the accepted answer, unless you are playing code golf :)

```
samples = [int(i in (1, 2, 3)) or i for i in samples]
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `int(True)` returns `1`.